# Changing Windows app shortcut properties without running the app in admin mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator, shortcuts

I'm trying to change font/layout/etc shortcut properties of a specific console app. For example, PowerShell 7. The shortcut resides in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerShell` folder, thus changing it requires admin rights.

I want to be able to change the shortcut without having to start the app itself using`Run as administrator", but I'm getting this error when I'm clicking OK to save the changes:

```
---------------------------
Error Updating Shortcut
---------------------------
Unable to modify the shortcut:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerShell\PowerShell 7 (x64).lnk.
Check to make sure it has not been deleted or renamed.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

More so, even if I do run it in the admin mode, some settings that I change still don't persist.

**Is there a user-friendly way of changing shortcuts like that, without having to launch the target app in the admin mode?**

[image: PowerShell 7 properties]

[image: Unable to modify shortcut]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, thanks to this ["How to Run Windows File Explorer Elevated (as Administrator)"](http://woshub.com/how-to-run-file-explorer-elevated) article. Sharing with the Windows community and my future self.

Steps:

1. <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Del</kbd> for Task Manager, then switch to the `Details` tab and add `Elevated` column;
2. Go to `File/Run new task` in Task Manager and run `taskkill.exe /f /im explorer.exe` (make sure to tick `[x] Create this task with administrative privileges`), that should kill the current running instance of Windows Explorer.
3. From `File/Run new task` in Task Manager and run `explorer.exe /nouaccheck`, that should start Explorer in elevated admin mode (check the `Elevated` column status).
4. Modify and save all the desired shortcuts. You should not see any `Error Updating Shortcut` errors this time.
5. Repeat step 2.
6. Finally, from `File/Run new task`, restart `explore.exe` in non-admin mode, this time make sure to untick `[ ] Create this task with administrative privileges` (verify that in the `Elevated` column).

[image: task manager]

[image: taskkill]

[image: explorer with admin rights]

[image: explorer non-admin]